# Post War Geopolitics?

Tags: warfare, politics, earth, geopolitics

I'm writing a story. 
In this story, a sufficiently advanced alien descends to Earth, and bestows esper abilities on a third of humanity.(A rank 5 electric Esper for example can generate a 100 Gigawatts(tentative) of electric power constantly).

Following that pandemonium broke out, and several factions, secret society and organisations tried to use the chaos as a means to further their agenda. Guilds were formed among espers, and the Third World War; The Guild War began and was fought for 2 years. The war did not degenerate into a Nuclear war, due to intervention by the Protagonist's former guild(a genius computing prodigy gained the ability to interface with electronics, and systematically locked down all nuclear armaments globally).

Our chief antagonist Arthur, is a member of a faction called the British Imperialists. He managed to outwit our genius protagonist and win over most of his former guild.

After the protagonist's defeat, he worked to unite the world into one Empire. About 2 thirds of the guilds joined him and in the two years since then, he managed to gain 75% support.

For the Geopolitics what I've got so far is:

The British Commonwealth, was united into "The Great Kingdom of Britain", due to the British Imperialists.

The former USSR forms "The Great Kingdom of Russia"

China and Taiwan have been united to form the Great Kingdom of China. 
Manchuria, Nepal, and some of China's neighbouring countries have been annexed by "The Great Kingdom of China".

I'm thinking of a United E.U, but I'm not sure.

Africa is divided; I'm not sure whether the divisions should be as they are now, or should be larger.

I don't know how South and Central America would be like.

Maybe Arab Asia and Northern Africa should unite into one Caliphate?

Oceania would be annexed by "The Great Kingdom of Britain"

Also, "The Great Kingdom of Britain", would have desired the USA, as it was former Crown territory.

So help please?

How'll the USA look like? How'll central and Southern America, Africa and the rest of Asia be? Should the EU be united?

I want a believable post war Geo politics.

Comment: This question is asking very open ended questions. Basically, you want the answerer to determine the state of politics in the entire world. That is too broad a topic for our Q&A site. A narrow question might say, "I expect the US to be like this, is that realistic." As it is, this question is far 'too broad' and I am voting to close.

Comment: handwave man, you is the one who tells the story, and it will be the way you will it to be. (however, that kingdoms idea - yeah why kingdoms, by not triads and anarchies). Any possible system can be explained how it could be formed, but it does not make it more real.

Answer (score 2):

I think your setting needs some more work if you want it to be believable.

- Consider if you want to *recreate* historical Empires, generally single European countries with their former colonies, or if you want to *create* new empires based on present-day or future politics. Doing both at one will lead to contradictions and tensions.
- The breakup of historical empires generally caused acrimony and reuniting the parts will be difficult. Consider what people in Zimbabwe thinks about the Brits, or what people in the Baltics think about Russians.
- South America might retain the split between Spanish speakers and Portugese speakers.
- The next years will decide if the EU breaks up or prospers. Something very interesting happened last week, a Polish politician was elected as EU Council President against the wishes of the Polish government. Either that's a big crack showing in the EU, or a step towards EU-wide political parties where ideology counts for more than nationality.

Side note, 100 GW electrical power are **a lot**.

Comment: @Actually the thing is that the crack is in Poland. And one nationalistic politician wanted to hurt his main oponent at any price, while the rest of the EU decided just to reelect acceptable incumbent and move to more complicated issues. EU wide political factions do exist, but they haven't matured yet.

Comment: Yeah it is. Well, I wanted a justifiable paradigm shift to render conventional warfare obsolete. (Nuclear warfare is averted due to the equivalent of seizing all nuclear weapons globally). So nation states may get crippled.